# How do I ensure accurate results of stress tests?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-12.04, performance-testing, stress-testing

I have written a script for a project that stress tests the cpu, the vm and the i/o whilst running vmstat, iostat and sar. The scripts all run for 30 seconds. My tutor has asked me however to ensure that the results are accurate? How can I ever be sure? Surely I just take the machine's word for it after running a few tests? The tests have been run for 60 seconds each and so have the commands to try and ensure a fair test, but how can I be sure that they are accurate according to my tutor's concerns? Any ideas?

The systems are server versions of Ubuntu 12.04, Debian 7 and Suse 11

Comment: Your tutor might be refering to making sure there are no superfluous programs/daemons running alongside the tests.

Comment: 30 seconds also sounds like a somewhat limited sampling window.  Perhaps run it multiple times during different times of day etc over a longer period of time to improve the statistical validity.

Comment: sorry I meant 60 seconds, they all run for 60 because I thought that was long enough but still short enough to run multiple times if needed. I have closed all other processes on both windows and linux and only have the one program-my virtual machine running. the tests are run with the stress command-no sysbench or anything used. any other way I could guarantee they are accurate? the results all seem the same after a few tests.

Comment: @paul perhaps collecting verifiable data on all of the above efforts you've made to ensure the validity of your results?

Comment: what do you mean by that? screenshots showing that nothing else is running in the background for example? or proof that i have run them several times? is that along the lines of what you mean?

Comment: @paul I suppose, it seems to me you're performing the tests diligently but your tutor is asking for more. Maybe you should ask him/her what exactly they want from you.

Comment: I have checked your comments with my tutor and they demonstrate suitable care for determining accuracy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know which are your tutor's concerns, so you should ask him!

"accuracy" usually means that your test results should not be offset by a factor you're not taking into account, like some CPU features being disabled or not used, differences in software configuration, etc.

What is it that you evaluate, anyway? Evaluating CPU performance is not the same as evaluating a particular hardware system, which is yet different if you consider the software as well. Basically, you need to eliminate all differences which are not part of your evaluation, and make sure the rest of the configuration is representative (e.g. installing a modern OS which supports all the features the CPU provides).

And remember that in the end you will always take the machine's word for it, there's just no other way. All you can say is that you have considered all factors you're aware of, and hope that the factors remaining unknown don't have a big influence.

Comment: I shared your comments with the tutor and they have accepted them. I have ensured that the principles of multiple tests, no background processes, closed windows programs and long time periods have been followed too. Thanks.